# IIS 301 Redirect from one Controller to another (including parameters) ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, iis, web-config

I renamed one of my controllers and now want to do a `HTTP 301` to the new URL. I prefer doing it from IIS so I don't pollute my `RouteConfig`. I also want to include any parameters included in the redirect.

I'm trying to achieve all of the following:

- `site.com/old` --> `301 site.com/new`
- `site.com/old/` --> `301 site.com/new/`
- `site.com/old?foo=bar` --> `301 site.com/new?foo=bar`
- etc

This is what I have so far but I can't get it to work:

```
<rule name="Redirect Old to New" pattern="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*\/old.*" />
    <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/new/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue appears to be with your RegEx. A URL in this context will never begin with a `/` and you should always match the beginning of the string `^`. Also, you need to define what to capture in order to supply the end of the redirect URL.

```
<rule name="301 Redirect Old to New">
    <!--
      matches         /old
      matches         /old?foo=123
      matches         /old/?foo=123
      matches         /old/older/oldest?foo=123
      doesn't match   /oldee/whatever
    -->
    <match url="^old(?:/|(?=\?)|$)(.*)"/>
    <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="new/{R:1}"/>
</rule>
```

Also, for SEO purposes I would say you are shooting yourself in the foot with your second option. You should either *always* use a trailing slash or *never* use one in your redirect. Pick one and then be consistent so all of your landing URLs are the same.

While there is nothing wrong with using IIS for 301 redirects per se, you should be sure you are sufficiently skilled at creating regular expressions if you take this approach. It also helps if you have a regular expression tester utility to ensure what you are writing works the way you expect.

There is a great tutorial to learn regular expressions here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: @globetrotter - I updated the regex again - it didn't match `/old` previously.

Comment: hi, thanks for the awesome answer. All my URLs have a trailing slash at the end (/old/ , /new/ etc) I have it configured in MVC that way. How should I change the rule to avoid bad SEO?

Comment: The way I have specified it will always add a trailing slash, so it should work for you as is. To make it *not* use the trailing slash, you would have to change the match regex to `^old(?:(?=\/)|(?=\?)|$)(/?.*)` and the redirect regex to `new{R:1}` (maybe not helpful to you, but others might want to know).

Comment: @NightOwl888  Can you help me about this redirect question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47614062/asp-net-301-redirect-to-new-url-from-web-config